# Can container overflowing fonts be adjusted with css?

Tags: html, css, svg, fonts, cairo

I'm rendering a text svg using handwriting style google fonts. Assume that I must use these fonts.

For this example, lets use [Princess Sofia](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Princess+Sofia#standard-styles)

### Setup

- rendering text svg to png via cairo svg in python
- text svg is being prepared in the browser

#### The Problem:

When creating a PNG out of the text svg with this font, some part of it is being cut off. The cut off part matches the areas that are not higlighted in the screenshot below:
[image: princess sofia characters]

#### Rendering result for A (cut off in the screenshot):

[image: letter P rendered]

#### Rendering result for P (NOT cut off in the screenshot):

[image: letter P rendered]

### Question

Is there a way to work around this using CSS or JS?

### What won't work

- "Kerning, stretching, font variants, word and letter spacing options, glyph orientations, baseline shifts and many other properties are not supported" by Cairo SVG

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to quickly test this without seeing some code reproducing the problem.

However, this may be rectified by using *font kerning* which can be specified in CSS using the `font-kerning` property:

```
font-kerning: normal;
```

Setting `font-kerning` to `normal` achieves the following effect:

> Font kerning information stored in the font must be applied.

The default is `auto`, which allows the browser to decide whether to use font kerning or not.  Forcing it to `normal` means that the kerning specified in the font itself *will* be used.

The docs for `font-kerning` can be read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-kerning).

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Would the svg code for the text svg and its parent help?

Comment: @RolandJegorov Anything that helps to reproduce the issue would be useful if that's possible

Comment: Please check https://stackblitz.com/edit/font-overflowing?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Also, I need to set the font styles via attributes because of the svg to png library limitations (cairo svg). Font kerning seems to not be set via an attribute. Not sure why. Regardless, if a font has no kerning, this attribute will not have any effect

Comment: Ah, actually found in Cairo SVG documentation - 

`Kerning, stretching, font variants, word and letter spacing options, glyph orientations, baseline shifts and many other properties are not supported.`